# How to Get A Random Value in the Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

Now I know there is the Object Info node and from what I hear, you can also do something with the Particle Info and Noise Texture nodes, but those are only in the material nodes, not the compositing nodes.

Anyway, I was wondering, is there any way to get a random value in the compositor without scripting and whatnot?

Comment: Use a Cloud texture? This can be translated in any direction to get variation.

Comment: There is a relatively easy way to get a random value using a driver and a really short python file...